# Could not load all ISAPI filters after installing VS2010 on Win 7 - 64bit

Tags: iis, windows-7, isapi

My website was working locally on my

Win 7 64 bit machine. I then installed VS2010 opted to not upgrade to .NET 4.0

Now when i go to my site i get the following error

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll" failed

In the event log i get

Could not load all ISAPI filters for site 'ESTORE'.  Therefore site startup aborted.

The site is using "DefaultAppPool" and Enabled 32-bit Application is set to True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, a little dumb on my part. I set Enable 32 bit back to true and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What version of .NET is associated with `DefaultAppPool`?

You need separate app pools for .NET 2.0 (with or without 3.0 & 3.5 assemblies) and 4.0.

(The .NET 4 installer run by VS2010 created separate 4.0 app pools, but that could be an artefact of previously having RC installed.)

Comment: Richard, DefaultAppPool is set to v2.0.5. I didn't install the rc. Just the full version that came out the other day.

Answer (score 0):

If the Enable 32-bit flag won't work for you, try to check your ISAPI filters in IIS.  I had some mysterious additional .net ISAPI filter on my dev machine that I couldn't account for in there (probably from some .net RC build I installed), and after removing/disabling it, all was working again.